# How to update a column of date type assigned with the latest value in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm dealing with my MariaDB via Spring Boot's JPA dependency.

I have a table that looks like the one described as below

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | varchar(32) | NO | PRIMARY | NULL | - |
| name | varchar(256) | YES | - | NULL | - |
| date | datetime(3) | NO | PRIMARY | NULL | - |
| ip | varchar(40) | NO | PRIMARY | NULL | - |

Thus, id, date, and ip fields are the composite primary key for this table.

And I was trying to update the `date` of the latest one out of matching result using the query like

```sql
UPDATE my_table SET date = NOW() WHERE
   id = 'finding_id' AND
   ip = 'finding_ip';
```

Since there were duplicated `id`-`ip` paired entries in the data like following,

| id | name | date | ip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **finding_id** | finding_name | *2022-03-28 17:27:39.617* | **finding_ip** |
| **finding_id** | finding_name | *2022-03-28 16:52:01.483* | **finding_ip** |
| another_id1 | another_name1 | 2022-03-28 16:29:39.552 | another_ip1 |
| another_id2 | another_name2 | 2022-03-28 16:29:24.435 | another_ip2 |

I've got an error message.

As a makeshift, I appended another restriction to the `where` clause to narrow the range of time to be like "in last 15 minutes".

But I'm looking for more elegant workaround for this problem.

Comment: You could join onto a sub-query from the table where you use `rank() over (partition by id, ip, order by timestamp) as rn` and add rn seconds to `now()` which would avoid having duplicate timestamps for the same combination of `ip, id`.

Comment: you could also use `row_number`

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL and MariaDB you can use ORDER BY and LIMIT in a update statement:

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET `date` = NOW() 
WHERE
   id = 'finding_id' AND
   ip = 'finding_ip'
ORDER BY `date` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Above will update the record with the highest date, within the filter because of the WHERE-clause, with the current datetime.

NOTE: It's better not to use any of the [RESERVED WORDS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) as a column name. You can, but then you have to use backticks around the fieldname.

Comment: Thanks for all of your helps including table rendering issue using markdown in the question!  And this answer solved my issue in the exact way that I'd expected.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the database schema.

You have a primary key which is a **UNIQUE** **composite** key of 3 columns and you want to be able to have **non-unique** sets in them.

Which unless you want to update the **Date** to a new made up one everytime (adding/substracting miliseconds) is not possible.

I would recommend since you don't seem to care for uniqueness of the 3 columns, change the index type from **PRIMARY** to **INDEX** (still composite), so you don't have the **UNIQUE** constraint.

After that add a new  "real" id column `primary_id` (or rename your other one, so the new one can be `id`) column which is just a normal **PRIMARY KEY** with Auto Increment turned on.